# Google Analytics Content Grouping by Extraction - extract 3rd level subdirectories

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I've been going round in circles with this one.

I'd like to perform a content grouping in google analytics that groups by a 3rd level subdirectory.

I can grab the second level successfully with the following regex

```
`/destinations/(.*?)/`
```

where the url is

```
mydomain.com/destinations/europe
mydomain.com/destinations/alaska
```

I get content groups of europe and alaska.

However, I also then want a grouping of the next level, for example

```
mydomain.com/destinations/europe/southampton
mydomain.com/destinations/europe/portugal
mydomain.com/destinations/alaska/somealaskanplace
```

to give me groupings of southampton, portugal and somealaskanplace
This means i need to effectively ignore whatever's in the second level and this is what i'm struggling with.

So far i have

```
`/destinations\/.*\/(.*?)/$`
```

but that's given me the domain name as a grouping

Can anyone help?  It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: please ignore the back ticks in the regex above!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Multiline flag On

Check this:

```
/.*?\/(destinations)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)/gm
```

Demo on Regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/2wvRIx/2

Comment: Are you sure `/gm` is supported in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `/` delimiters. GA may be interpreting your last `/$` as being a slash and then end-of-string. Try making it just `/destinations/.*/(.*?)$` (note that GA regex does not require you to escape slashes).